# C# Address Model - Concatenate Address1, Address2 etc into a computed field

Tags: c#, oop, model

I have an address model in my application:

```
**[Key]**  
public int CustomerAddressId { get; set; }  
public string CompanyName { get; set; }  
public string Address1 { get; set; }  **NOT NULL**  
public string Address2 { get; set; }  
public string Address3 { get; set; }  
public string City { get; set; }  
public string County { get; set; }  
public string Postcode { get; set; }  **NOT NULL**
**[ForeignKey]**  
public int CountryId { get; set; }
```

I have a Country model with CountryId, CountryNameCustomer

I would like to add a computed field to my customer address model which outputs a single address line, taking into account any fields which may be NULL.

For example, for the following address:

Address 1: 4 Raymond Street
Address 2: Leyton
City: London
Postcode: W13 5TY

I would like my computed field to be "4 Raymond Road, Leyton, London, W13 5TY".

I am not sure of the most elegant way to achieve this.

I could do something like the following:

```
var address = "";  
if(CompanyName != null){address += CompanyName + ",";}
if(Address1 != null){address += Address1 + ",";}
```

and so on...

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

All the best.

Comment: You can try using interpolated string, it might make the code a bit more compact, but they way you wrote is clear and readable.  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Answer (score 0):

Override `ToString` in your 'custom address' class like this:

```
        public override string ToString()
        {
            var parts = new List<string>();
            parts.AddRange(new [] {CompanyName, Address1, Address2, Address3, City, County, Postcode});
            return string.Join(", ", parts.Where(part => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(part)));
        }
```